# find matching word in the sentence of 2 diferent files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Im using pandas to convert excel to dataframe

I have 2 excel file lets call it A and B
here is A file
[File A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq2Ap.png)

and this is file B
[File B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihoh6.png)

my question is how to scan every single sentence on each row of file A by every word in file B

and then if match, change the label in File A using label in file B in which containing word matched with file B

im using python 3

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import pandas as pd
dfA = pd.read_excel('A.xlsx')  
dfB = pd.read_excel('B.xlsx')  
for indexA, rowA in dfA.iterrows():
    for indexB, rowB in dfB.iterrows():
        if (rowB['text'] in rowA['text']):
            dfA.at[indexA,'label'] = rowA['label'] + int(rowB['label'])
```